# Create custom error on release build

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, custom-errors

Is there any way I can create a custom error message that displays as a reminder to myself and other colleagues that there is unfinished code in the app, if they try and do a release build?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: possibly like this: http://macdevelopertips.com/xcode/xcode-fixme-and-todo.html ?

Comment: Thanks for replying. That is useful but it would still allow my colleagues to build and deploy a potential buggy app.

Comment: True - that's why i didn't put it as an answer :) Hopefully you'll get the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
#ifndef DEBUG
#error Don't release this
#endif
```

Comment: Thats exactly what i was looking for. Release builds fail and debug builds run fine. Thanks a lot!